# Convert string matrix to numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have matrices of arbitrary dimension, formatted similarly to the example below. They come from an external source and the formatting cannot be changed.

```
[[[1.65 0.53 0 1][0.99 1.41 0 1][0.38 1.37 0 1][0 0 1 1][1.10 0.69 0 1][0 0 1 1][0.60 1.21 0 1][0.99 1.04 0 1][1.86 1.20 0 1][0 0 1 1][1.66 0.68 0 1][0.96 0.75 0 1][0.86 0.80 0 1][1.13 0.97 0 1][1.86 1.48 0 1][0 0 1 1][0.71 1.10 0 1][1.43 0.58 0 1][1.34 0.63 0 1][1.37 1.45 0 1][0.36 1.08 0 1][0 0 1 1][0.60 1.18 0 1][1.08 0.64 0 1][0.99 0.58 0 1][1.57 1.16 0 1][0.87 1.39 0 1][0.48 1.21 0 1][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0]][[1.52 1.01 0 1][0.93 0.62 0 1][1.41 0.52 0 1][1.66 0.83 0 1][0 0 1 1][1.02 1.03 0 1][0.98 0.92 0 1][0 0 1 1][0.65 0.90 0 1][0 0 1 1][1.27 0.61 0 1][0.41 0.79 0 1][1.23 1.04 0 1][0.56 0.70 0 1][0 0 1 1][1.81 0.90 0 1][0 0 1 1][1.71 0.57 0 1][1.53 1.06 0 1][1.28 1.42 0 1][1.50 0.91 0 1][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0]][[0 0 1 1][0.53 1.17 0 1][0.24 0.54 0 1][1.88 0.68 0 1][0 0 1 1][1.33 0.68 0 1][0.32 0.55 0 1][1.28 0.73 0 1][0.49 1.13 0 1][1.45 1.28 0 1][0.66 1.47 0 1][0 0 1 1][0.76 1.10 0 1][1.95 0.78 0 1][0 0 1 1][0.56 0.61 0 1][0.84 1.05 0 1][1.07 0.59 0 1][1.79 0.95 0 1][1.93 1.02 0 1][1.93 1.16 0 1][0 0 1 1][0.55 0.58 0 1][0.29 1.13 0 1][1.46 0.50 0 1][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0]][[1.71 0.50 0 1][0.70 1.35 0 1][0 0 1 1][0.90 0.83 0 1][1.81 0.97 0 1][1.64 1.35 0 1][1.21 1.15 0 1][0.54 0.50 0 1][0 0 1 1][0.62 0.72 0 1][0.86 1.38 0 1][0 0 1 1][1.76 1.15 0 1][1.83 1.43 0 1][0.20 0.51 0 1][0.81 0.65 0 1][0 0 1 1][0.51 0.79 0 1][1.09 1.43 0 1][1.65 1.03 0 1][1.47 1.49 0 1][0 0 1 1][1.57 0.97 0 1][0.99 0.93 0 1][1.82 0.66 0 1][1.84 1.01 0 1][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0]][[0 0 1 1][1.36 0.94 0 1][1.61 0.64 0 1][0.99 1.03 0 1][1.43 1.12 0 1][1.09 1.16 0 1][0.40 1.40 0 1][0 0 1 1][0.86 0.56 0 1][0.54 0.80 0 1][0.77 1.04 0 1][0 0 1 1][1.38 0.61 0 1][0.37 1.38 0 1][1.12 1.28 0 1][0 0 1 1][1.87 0.67 0 1][1.75 0.52 0 1][0.31 0.52 0 1][0.99 0.88 0 1][0 0 1 1][1.38 1.30 0 1][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0][0 0 0 0]]]
```

How can I convert this into NumPy form? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641087/undo-pretty-print-from-numpy) suggests using [`fromstring`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html#numpy.fromstring); however, the documentation says this only works for 1D matrices.

Comment: Make sure there are no '...'

Comment: In the future, try to use a more portable string format.  As you can see from the answers this style requires editing.  The string format of `arr.tolist()` is better.  `csv` format is a good portable format for 2d arrays.  `np.save/load` is best for general arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj: I do not have control over the format and anticipate that my arrays, like the one in the example I show, will often have >2 dimensions.

Comment: If the arrays are large enough, that print display will be truncated, making recovery impossible.

Comment: @hpaulj: You may be working under the belief that the matrices are being pretty-printed by NumPy. That is not so. Regardless, this is the form the matrices I want to process are in and it cannot be changed. There's no need to suggest otherwise or to imply limitations which may not be relevant.

Comment: I've edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends, if it is already a `list` you could just use `np.array()` to convert it directly, if it is a string you probably need to insert `,` first to make it valid Python list. Here would be an example incase it is a string

```
import ast
import numpy as np

myString = "<YOUR STRING ABOVE>"
myString = myString.replace(" ", ",") # Replace [0 0 0 0] with [0,0,0,0]
myString = myString.replace("][", "],[") # Replace [0,0,0,0][0,0,0,0] with [0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0] 
myList = ast.literal_eval(s) # Turn string into a list
myArr = np.array(myList) # Turn list into np_array
```

Hope it helps, if your data already is a list you can just skip straight to `np.array(myList)`

Dimensions of the array I created from the data above:

```
myArr.shape
(5, 33, 4)
```

Edit: Changed eval() to ast.literal_eval as suggested by @b_c

Comment: You should use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead of `eval`.

Comment: ast.literal.eval is good but won't make much of a difference if the data is hardcoded - whoever, yes.  I will change my answer to use that.

Comment: @b_c I have edited my answer, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Without line breaks, that is anything but "pretty".

I think the fastest way to go there is to use regular expressions search/replace to add a `,` between space-separated digits and between `][`. this however won't be very smart and would break on corner cases (like numbers ending in `.`), so you may have to fine-tune the idea:

Now, on trying it here, the old saying proves itself once more as correct: "if you have one problem that needs regular expressions, you have two problems" (unknown author).

The problem is that as some of the numbers are composed by a single digit, when this number is matched for the comma placing for the number before it, it is not available for the regex engine to match it before the number *after* it.

So we have to go after "look ahead matches" and "look behind matches" using the `(?=...)` syntax - which enables one to match just the place where we want to add the ",".

after that you have a string where you can use  "eval" to have a nested list structure which can be passed directly to `numpy.array`.

```py
import numpy as np
import re
from ast import literal_eval

b = re.sub(r"((?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)|(?<=\])\s*?(?=\[))", ", " , a) 
c = np.array(literal_eval(b))
```

Of course, if you always have one space between numbers, and no-space or breaks between "][", simple string replacing, with no regexps is much easier to go. Use the regexp if you have loose spacing in your input data.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this:

```py
import ast
import numpy as np

def StringToMatrix(txtmat):
    txtmat = txtmat.replace(" ",",").replace("][","],[")
    try:
        ret = np.array(ast.literal_eval(txtmat))
    except:
        ret = None
    return ret
```